# Splitting a string similar to ip addresses using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing, regex-group

I want to have a regular expression which will split on seeing a '.'(dot)

For example:

```
Input: '1.2.3.4.5.6'
Output : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

What I have tried:-

```
>>> pattern = '(\d+)(\.(\d+))+'
>>> test = '192.168.7.6'
>>> re.findall(pat, test)
```

What I get:-

```
[('192', '.6', '6')]
```

What I expect from `re.findall()`:-

```
[('192', '168', '7', '6')]
```

Could you please help in pointing what is wrong?

My thinking -
In `pattern = '(\d+)(\.(\d+))+'`, initial `(\d+)` will find first number i.e. `192` Then `(\.(\d+))+` will find one or more occurences of the form `'.<number>'` i.e. `.168` and `.7` and `.6`

[EDIT:]
This is a simplified version of the problem I am solving.
In reality, the input can be-

```
192.168 dot 7 {dot} 6
```

and expected output is still `[('192', '168', '7', '6')]`.

Once I figure out the solution to extract `.168`, `.7`, `.6` like patterns, I can then extend it to `dot 168`, `{dot} 7` like patterns.

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with `test.split('.')` if all you want to do is split on the dots? Don't swat flies with a sledgehammer.

Comment: I had guessed this would come, but my problem is different from what I am asking. basically, instead of numbers, there is complex strings. Instead of '.' there can actually be "dot" i.e. 192 dot 168 dot 7 dot 6, like this and their combinations etc.

Comment: In that case, can you update your question and post some of the actual data you want help with? It's not much use for us to give you solutions to a different problem from what you're trying to solve.

Comment: I tried this regex and it gave me the result you wants, (\d+)[\.]*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to find the numbers, the regex `\d+` should be enough to find numbers separated by any other token/separator:

```
re.findall("\d+", test)
```

This should work on any of those cases:

```
>>> re.findall("\d+", "192.168.7.6")
['192', '168', '7', '6']
>>> re.findall("\d+", "192.168 dot 7 {dot} 6 | 125 ; 1")
['192', '168', '7', '6', '125', '1']
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)